# Several and independent workspaces

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

For my training with ROS, I would like to create an additional workspace (e.g. in `~/catkin_ws2/`) next to an existing one (`~/catkin_ws/`). Assuming that ROS Indigo was already installed on my computer, I followed the ROS tutorials to setup *another* catkin workspace :

$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws2/src/
$ cd ~/catkin_ws2/src/
$ catkin_init_workspace
</code></pre>
Then I run `catkin_make` in `~/catkin_ws2/` and added the lines
<pre><code>source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
source /home/myhome/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash
</code></pre>
at the end of my .bashrc file in `/home/myhome/`. I specify that I already did all of this with the previous workspace.<br>
But when I echoed the `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, there were still the path of `~/catkin_ws/` in it.
Why is it still here since I didn't tell to ROS that the first workspace still exists ?

Many thanks for your replies.


---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203851/several-and-independent-workspaces/) by [anonymous21729](https://answers.ros.org/users/21729/anonymous21729/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2015-02-26


Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That means that the workspace in `~/catkin_ws/` was sourced when you built the workspace in `~/catkin_ws2/`. You'll have to clear the build, devel, and install folders of `~/catkin_ws2/` and in a new terminal (without sourcing stuff in your `~/.bashrc`) source `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` and then build `~/catkin_ws2/` with `catkin_make`.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3